# Hibernate Search FullTextFilter cache not working

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, lucene-filters

I have the following entity declaration:

```
@FullTextFilterDefs({
  @FullTextFilterDef(name = "withStock", impl = WithStockFilterFactory.class, cache = FilterCacheModeType.INSTANCE_ONLY),
  @FullTextFilterDef(name = "onlyActive", impl = OnlyActiveFilterFactory.class, cache = FilterCacheModeType.INSTANCE_ONLY),
})
public class Article {

    @Column
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
    protected Boolean activo;
}
```

And this is my filter:

```
public class OnlyActiveFilterFactory {

  private Boolean onlyActive;

  public void setOnlyActive(Boolean onlyActive) {
    this.onlyActive = onlyActive;
  }

  @Factory
  public Query getFilter() {
    List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<>();
    terms.add(new Term("active", "true"));

    if (!onlyActive) {
      terms.add(new Term("active", "false"));
    }

    return new QueryWrapperFilter(new TermsQuery(terms));
  }
}
```

But when I perform a search everything is ok until I change the value of `active` for an instance, as it would be always returned in any search despite of the value of the parameter `onlyActive` set to the filter; for every other instance works fine.

This happens until I rebuild the **whole index**. I tried to reindex the entity after changing it's `active` value, like this but with no luck:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
fullTextEntityManager.index(article);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, 
The method in the repository that changed the `active` attribute value was annotated with `@Query` so that operation to the database won't force a reindex and cache update.